# MatLab error when plotting function

Tags: matlab

So I have to draw some graphs in MatLab.

At first I save this as a .m file:

```
function y = f(x)
y = sqrt((abs(sin(21*pi*x)))/(2+sin(20*pi*x)));
```

Then I do:

```
x=[0:0.05:1]
y=f(x)
```

and then when I need to draw the graph, using

```
plot(x,f)
```

I get this error:

```
??? Input argument "x" is undefined.
Error in ==> f at 2
y = sqrt((abs(sin(21*pi*x)))/(2+sin(20*pi*x)));
```

Can someone tell me what is the problem here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to have the `./` operator instead of `/` when dividing two vectors element by element. Try this instead

```
x = 0:0.05:1;
y = sqrt((abs(sin(21*pi*x)))./(2+sin(20*pi*x)));
plot(x,y)
```

[image]

Comment: hm.. i still get the error but it draws at least, a triangle :)

Comment: sorry, typo of 0.5 instead of 0.05 in the x step. I've edited the answer, try again.